# Remove xsi:type attribute on specific XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

For the sake of simplicity I have the following XML and I need to remove only `xsi:type="YYY"` from `Root/Foo/Bar` using XSLT stylesheet.

```
<Root>
    <ChildElement xsi:type="XXX" />
    <Foo>
        <Bar xsi:type="YYY" />
    </Foo>
    <AndAnotherOne xsi:type="ZZZ" />
</Root>
```

I was able to remove it for all elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>

    <xsl:template match="@xsi:type" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I fail if I try to match only the attribute I need to remove:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>

    <xsl:template match="Root/Foo/Bar/@xsi:type" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide runnable code: add the missing namespace declarations to both the input and the stylesheet.

Comment: As you can see here, with proper namespace declarations in place the code works as expected: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRXr9g.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason why

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:type" />
```

would successfully remove all occurrences of the `xsi:type` attribute, but

```
<xsl:template match="Root/Foo/Bar/@xsi:type" />
```

would have no effect at all is that one or more of the `Root`, `Foo` and `Bar` elements is in a namespace of its own.

Although the provided XML input does not show any namespace declaration for these elements, it is also missing the namespace declaration for the `xsi` prefix. So it is very likely that the real input contains a default namespace declaration alongside `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.

Answer (score -3):

Use the following template match to specifically remove the attribute value that contains 'yyy':

<xsl:template match="@xsi:type[.='YYY']" />

Comment: The question is how to remove an attribute **on specific element**, not how to remove an attribute with specific value.

Comment: In such case, you can add the parent element to the match attribute: <xsl:template match="@xsi:type[.='YYY' and parent::Bar]" />

Comment: More precisely for specific xpath you can use <xsl:template match="/Root/Foo/Bar/@xsi:type[.='YYY']" />

Comment: So you're saying that `<xsl:template match="/Root/Foo/Bar/@xsi:type[.='YYY']" />` would work while  `<xsl:template match="Root/Foo/Bar/@xsi:type" />` does not? And how would you explain this?

Comment: If we have to access elements from root level there must be slash present at the beginning of the XPATH otherwise it will not find the path from the current context. I hope this helps! You can try changing the XSL accordingly at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRXr9g and check.

Comment: I am afraid you are completely wrong about that - as the linked demo clearly shows. A *match pattern* is not a *path*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - both will work; however, the first one will remove attribute with specific value and the second one will remove attribute with any value.

Comment: Maybe you should read the question again.